# how can I optimize my app because it always crashes

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I am working on a project in in flutter using mapbox and my app always crashes. how can I stop the navigation working when I click the back button.

I just used navigator push to go to another page that enables navigation.

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        return RestaurantsMap();
                      }));
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.route_outlined,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
```

after going to the other page and go back to where it should be, the app crashes. I think that the navigation is still running when I pop the page that has navigation

```
        class _RestaurantsMapState extends State<RestaurantsMap> {
      // Mapbox related
      LatLng latLng = getLatLngFromSharedPrefs();
      late CameraPosition _initialCameraPosition;
      late MapboxMapController controller;
      late List<CameraPosition> _kRestaurantList;
      List<Map> carouselData = [];

      // Carousel related
      int pageIndex = 0;
      late List<Widget> carouselItems;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: latLng, zoom: 15);

        // Calculate the distance and time from data in SharedPreferences
        for (int index = 0; index < restaurants.length; index++) {
          num distance = getDistanceFromSharedPrefs(index) / 1000;
          num duration = getDurationFromSharedPrefs(index) / 60;
          carouselData
              .add({'index': index, 'distance': distance, 'duration': duration});
        }

        carouselData.sort(((a, b) => a['duration'] < b['duration'] ? 0 : 1));

        // Generate the list of carousel widgets
        carouselItems = List<Widget>.generate(
            restaurants.length,
            (index) => carouselCard(carouselData[index]['index'],
                carouselData[index]['distance'], carouselData[index]['duration']));

        // initialize map symbols in the same order as carousel widgets
        _kRestaurantList = List<CameraPosition>.generate(
            restaurants.length,
            (index) => CameraPosition(
                target: getLatLngFromRestaurantData(carouselData[index]['index']),
                zoom: 15));

        initializeLocationAndSave();
      }

      void initializeLocationAndSave() async {
        // Ensure all permissions are collected for Locations
        Location _location = Location();
        bool? _serviceEnabled;
        PermissionStatus? _permissionGranted;

        _serviceEnabled = await _location.serviceEnabled();
        if (!_serviceEnabled) {
          _serviceEnabled = await _location.serviceEnabled();
        }

        _permissionGranted = await _location.hasPermission();
        if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
          _permissionGranted = await _location.requestPermission();
        }

        // Get capture the current user location
        LocationData _locationData = await _location.getLocation();
        LatLng currentLatLng =
            LatLng(_locationData.latitude!, _locationData.longitude!);

        // Store the user location in sharedPreferences
        sharedPreferences.setDouble('latitude', _locationData.latitude!);
        sharedPreferences.setDouble('longitude', _locationData.longitude!);

        // Get and store the directions API response in sharedPreferences
        for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
          Map modifiedResponse = await getDirectionsAPIResponse(currentLatLng, i);
          saveDirectionsAPIResponse(i, json.encode(modifiedResponse));
        }
      }

      _addSourceAndLineLayer(int index, bool removeLayer) async {
        // Can animate camera to focus on the item
        controller
            .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kRestaurantList[index]));

        // Add a polyLine between source and destination
        Map geometry = getGeometryFromSharedPrefs(carouselData[index]['index']);
        final _fills = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": [
            {
              "type": "Feature",
              "id": 0,
              "properties": <String, dynamic>{},
              "geometry": geometry,
            },
          ]
        };

        // Remove lineLayer and source if it exists
        if (removeLayer == true) {
          await controller.removeLayer("lines");
          await controller.removeSource('fills');
        }

        // Add new source and lineLayer
        await controller.addSource("fills", GeojsonSourceProperties(data: _fills));
        await controller.addLineLayer(
            "fills",
            "lines",
            LineLayerProperties(
              lineColor: Colors.green.toHexStringRGB(),
              lineBlur: "round",
              lineJoin: "round",
              lineWidth: 2,
            ));
      }

      _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) async {
        this.controller = controller;
      }

      _onStyleLoadedCallback() async {
        for (CameraPosition _kRestaurant in _kRestaurantList) {
          await controller.addSymbol(SymbolOptions(
            geometry: _kRestaurant.target,
            iconSize: 0.2,
            iconImage: "assets/icon/food.png",
          ));
        }
        _addSourceAndLineLayer(0, false);
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Restaurants Map'),
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
                  child: MapboxMap(
                    accessToken: dotenv.env['MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'],
                    initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
                    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                    onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoadedCallback,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    myLocationTrackingMode: MyLocationTrackingMode.TrackingGPS,
                    minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(14, 17),
                  ),
                ),
                CarouselSlider(
                    items: carouselItems,
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                        height: 105,
                        viewportFraction: 0.6,
                        initialPage: 0,
                        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        onPageChanged:
                            (int index, CarouselPageChangedReason reason) {
                          setState(() {
                            pageIndex = index;
                          });
                          _addSourceAndLineLayer(index, true);
                        }))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              controller.animateCamera(
                  CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_initialCameraPosition));
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all of the code is fine. to fix the crashing issue, just replace the

before

```
myLocationEnabled: true,
```

after

```
myLocationEnabled: false,
```

Answer (score 1):

how can I stop the navigation working when I click the back button. ?

- to stop the navigation while the back button is clicked you need to contain your screen widget (like the schafold) in a widget called (WillPopScope) and this widget require two parameters
  1 - the child parameter and this will hold your widget
  2 - the onWillPop parameter and this will hold an async function that return bool(true or false) , if you return true the pop action will happened , if you return a false the pop action will not happened , the function example :

  ```
  () async{
    // your logic when the user click the back button.

    // true will go back , false will not move from this screen.
    return false;
  }
  ```

Comment: I have already tried your suggestion in using willpop but it still crashes after a few seconds I clicked the return button

Comment: what's the logic in the willpop function  before return false , comment this logic and see if it still crash then the logic is not the problem